# use of $location in chrome app throwing error

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

The moment I am adding `$location`

```
function DocsController($scope, $location,$http, gdocs) {
```

the app throws this error

```
Refused to load the script 

'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

main.html:1 Refused to load the script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

main.html:1 Refused to load the script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

extensions::platformApp:17 history.pushState is not available in packaged apps.(anonymous function) @ extensions::platformApp:17
angular-1.1.0.min.js:60 TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessToken' of undefined
    at Object.DocsController.$scope.toggleAuth (app.js:162)
    at new DocsController (app.js:180)
    at d (angular-1.1.0.min.js:27)
    at Object.instantiate (angular-1.1.0.min.js:27)
    at angular-1.1.0.min.js:50
    at angular-1.1.0.min.js:42
    at m (angular-1.1.0.min.js:6)
    at k (angular-1.1.0.min.js:42)
    at e (angular-1.1.0.min.js:38)
    at k (angular-1.1.0.min.js:42)
```

Basic search tells me $location can be used. it's a problem with my approach

Comment: Are you using Angular v1.1.0 with v1.4.8 of all the other libraries? Does the issue continue if you reference Angular v1.4.8? Mixing versions of Angular libraries usually results in strange behavior.

Comment: I updated everything to 1.5.3 and angular material to 1.0.7. The error stays

Comment: Have you checked the [Angular documentation on CSP](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp)?

Comment: @lex If you are asking whether I have used ng-csp or not then the answer is yes. Apart from that I have read in multiple places that what I am doing should work baring some small mistake which I am not able to spot.